# Use esmodules on aws lambda and serverless get "require is not defined in ES module scope"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, es6-modules

I'm trying to dev a script on aws lambda through nodejs, serverless and using es modules

I got this error all the time:

```
{
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
        "This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.",
        "    at file:///var/task/s_getStatus.js:2:21",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"
    ]
}
```

I understand that somewhere a script still use commonjs style code but can't find it on local. When running with serverless-offline, no problem too (code is working).

My handler code is simple as this:

```
export default async function () {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ status: true }),
  };
}
```

the code of main script (handler.js) is:

```
'use strict';

export {default as getStatus} from './handlers/get_status/index.js';
```

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "...-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "repository": "...-api.git",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "local": "sls offline",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-kms": "3.348.0",
    "serverless-plugin-tracing": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "serverless-offline": "12.0.4",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

My serverless file:

```
org: mathkr
app: healthcheck-api
service: healthcheck-api
frameworkVersion: '3'
useDotenv: true
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: eu-west-3
  tracing:
    lambda: true
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - xray:PutTraceSegments
        - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
      Resource:
        - '*'
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-tracing
functions:
  getStatus:
    handler: handler.getStatus
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: /status
          method: get
          cors: false
```

Nothing crazy. The point is, my opinion, on the 'var/task/s_getStatus.js:2:21' part of the errror. Seems that somewhere something uses require instruction but what ? It seems that in package.json file, the instruction type: 'module' is well defined. So I don't understand what i'm missing...

Is serverless translating code to commonjs ? Do i forget somewhere an option to setup to tell use esm ?

Comment: Could it be that `serverless-plugin-tracing` is only [published as a cjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-tracing?activeTab=code) module?

Comment: Have already tried to remove it, no changes. Sadly...

Comment: @MathKimRobin Does my answer clarifies your question?

Comment: Yes thanks @RobinThomas, didn't had time to try again before today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `app` and `org` keys in your `serverless.yml` file, its using Serverless Dashboard plugin for deployment.

Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't have an ESM support and hence is using `require()` statements.

At the moment, there is no plan to support ESM in Serverless Dashboard. Refer: https://github.com/serverless/dashboard-plugin/issues/564

So you have a couple of options:

1. Remove Serverless Dashboard (since its already deprecated). You can do this by removing the `app` and `org` keys from your `serverless.yml` file.
2. Migrate from Serverless Dashboard to [Serverless Console](https://console.serverless.com/), which already supports ES Modules.
3. Rewrite your application logic using CommonJS (instead of ES Modules).

Comment: additional point, if option 1/2, I needed to play this: `serverless config credentials --provider aws --key <Access Key ID> --secret <Secret Access Key>`